# Customize ITHIT AjaxFilebrowser toolbar

Tags: ithit-ajax-file-browser

We are using AjaxWebBrowser provided by ITHIT. http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser

I need to add custom buttons on toolbar for mobile view of ITHIT Ajax file browser control. I could do it for normal view using toolbar setting. I am not sure how do same for mobile browser view.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately currently there is no API for toolbar customization in mobile and tablet versions of IT Hit Ajax File Browser. The [toolbar customization API](http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser/programming/toolbar_customization) is currently available only for desktop version. We are working on the new API that will provide customization for mobile version soon.

The payed version of IT Hit Ajax File Browser is provided with full source codes, so you can customize the toolbar there.